# Ant seems to ignore jar generated by Proguard while packaging apk

Tags: android, ant, proguard

I have a Jenkins build server for building Android APKs with ant and Android (SDK Revision 18). Releasing APKs is working fine. However if i enable proguard by providing a proguard.cfg and pointing to it by "proguard.config=proguard.cfg" in the project.properties the following seems to happen:

Proguard is executed (as seen from shell output and the existence of mappings.txt and seeds.txt afterwards)
an apk is generated. However the Stacktraces generated by the APK are not obfuscated at all.

Anybody got an idee on this? It seems that the jar generated by proguard is for some reasons not included in the apk.

---

Here is my Proguard Config

> -optimizationpasses 5
>       -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
>       -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
>       -dontpreverify
>       -verbose
>       -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
>
> ```
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
> -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
> -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
> -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
> -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
> -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>     native <methods>;
> }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
> }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
> }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
>    public void *(android.view.View);
> }
>
> -keepclassmembers enum * {
>     public static **[] values();
>     public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
> }
>
> -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
>   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
> }
>
> #ACRA specifics
> # we need line numbers in our stack traces otherwise they are pretty useless
> -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
> -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
>
> # ACRA needs "annotations" so add this... 
> -keepattributes *Annotation*
>
> # keep this class so that logging will show 'ACRA' and not a obfuscated name like 'a'.
> # Note: if you are removing log messages elsewhere in this file then this isn't necessary
> -keep class org.acra.ACRA {
>         *;
> }
>
> # keep this around for some enums that ACRA needs
> -keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {
>    *;
> }
>
> # keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
> -keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
> {
> public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
> }
>
> # keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
> -keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
> {
> public org.acra.ErrorReporter$ReportsSenderWorker handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
> }
> ```

The mappings.txt states that my code is obfuscated:

```
de.cellular.crashtest.ObfuscateThisClass -> de.cellular.crashtest.b:
```

However it is not obfuscated in the reported Stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was just a jenkins configuration problem: the apk was archived from the `bin/` directory but the obfuscated one was in `release/`